# $ systemctl start mongodb returns failed (status=100)

Tags: mongodb, service, systemctl

My problem is simple yet the solution isn't easily found.

On my server I've had mongodb running for a few months and suddenly it stopped working. I start mongodb using `$ systemctl start mongodb` but it doesn't work anymore.

The response I get when I run `$ systemctl status mongodb` is:

- Active: failed
- Process: ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
- (code=exited, status=100)

What could it be? I've got a back-up of .ns and .0/.1/.2 files.